# Variable nesting depth inside table

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, procedural-programming, iteration, functional-style

I hope my title makes sense. The idea is the make a function in which a set of variables, $l_1$, $l_2$, etc. are accessible inside the innermost body of a nested (/folded) function. Each of these iterators would depend on the previous one, and takes an identical maximum value of `Y`.

I've chosen the `Table` command for this. The idea is that I have a helper list which builds `{{l_1+bounds},{l_2+bounds},...` `X` number of times, that is the last l is `l_X`.

To illustrate what the preferred output is, consider the following table, with associated value `progress` to count the number of times Mathematica loops through the table body.

```
progress = 0;
Y = 40;
Do[Table[progress += 1;, {l\[LetterSpace]1, l\[LetterSpace]0 + 1, 
    Y}], {l\[LetterSpace]0, Range[Y]}];
Print@progress
```

with result `780`, and it appears that each iterator can be accessed inside the innermost body (required for my use case, and not shown here explicitly).

Here is also the case for one level of nesting deeper:

```
progress = 0;
Do[
 Table[
  progress += 1;
  , {l\[LetterSpace]1, 
   l\[LetterSpace]0 + 1, Y}, {l\[LetterSpace]2, 
   l\[LetterSpace]1 + 1, Y}]
 , {l\[LetterSpace]0, Range[Y]}] 
Print@progress
```

The result here is `9880` for the value of progress.

The idea is to reproduce the above functionality automatically, by only specifying the depth of the nesting `X` and of course the upper bound `Y`.

What follows are two non-working examples. The first idea is to simply feed the iterators remotely by some replacement rule. But no dice: the `Table` won't accept a `List`, which is what `helperlist` outputs. So for example:

```
progress = 0;
Do[
   Table[
    progress += 1;
    , helperlist]
   , {l\[LetterSpace]0, Range[Y]}]  /. 
 helperlist -> {{l\[LetterSpace]1, l\[LetterSpace]0 + 1, 
    Y}, {l\[LetterSpace]2, l\[LetterSpace]1 + 1, Y}}
Print@progress
```

One would expect a combination of `Flatten[#,1]` or some related function to massage this `helperlist` into something that could be fed to `Table`, but I have unfortunately not found anything that worked.

The closest to the desired output is in fact not achieved through `Table`, but by `Fold`ing `Do`:

```
progress = 0;
X = 2;
Y = 40;
helperlist := 
  Reverse[{ToExpression["l\[LetterSpace]" <> ToString[#]], 
      ToExpression["l\[LetterSpace]" <> ToString[# - 1]] + 1, Y} & /@ 
    Range[X]];
Quiet@Do[Fold[Do, Unevaluated[progress++], 
   helperlist], {l\[LetterSpace]0, Range[Y]}];
Print@progress
```

But using `Quiet` is not considered good coding, and neither is using so many `Do` loops, for that matter.

--

The "dream" is that the above variable number iterators can be fulfilled as a second argument to `Table`. Something along the lines of:

```
progress = 0;
X = 2;
Y = 40;
helperlist := {ToExpression["l\[LetterSpace]" <> ToString[#]], 
     ToExpression["l\[LetterSpace]" <> ToString[# - 1]] + 1, Y} & /@ 
   Range[X];
Do[
  Table[
   progress += 1;
   , helperlist]
  , {l\[LetterSpace]0, Range[Y]}];
Print@progress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Subset iterator**

Maybe you could do something like:

```
X = 3;
Y = 5;
Table[l[i] = Indexed[g, i], {i, X}];
Table[{l[1], l[3]}, {g, Subsets[Range[Y],{X}]}]
```

> {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 
>     5}}

You could create a function to do this:

```
SetAttributes[iteratedTable,HoldAll]

iteratedTable[e_, g_Symbol, iterations_, max_] := Block[{g = Indexed[\[FormalL], #]&},
    Table[e, {\[FormalL], Subsets[Range@max, {iterations}]}]
]
```

Simple example:

```
iteratedTable[h[l[1], l[3], l[2]], l, 3, 5]
```

> {h[1, 3, 2], h[1, 4, 2], h[1, 5, 2], h[1, 4, 3], h[1, 5, 3], h[1, 5, 4], 
>    h[2, 4, 3], h[2, 5, 3], h[2, 5, 4], h[3, 5, 4]}

Your examples:

```
progress = 0;
iteratedTable[progress++, l, 2, 40];
progress
```

> 780

and:

```
progress = 0;
iteratedTable[progress++, l, 3, 40];
progress
```

> 9880

**Nested iterators**

An alternate approach that is similar to yours is:

```
SetAttributes[iteratedTable, HoldAll]
iteratedTable[e_, g_, iter_, max_] := ReleaseHold @ Hold[Table][
    Hold[e],
    Sequence @@ Table[{g[i], If[i==1, 1, g[i-1]+1], max}, {i, iter}]
]
```

**Avoiding indexed variables**

If you must have symbols instead of indexed variables, I think you should give the function the list of symbols. So:

```
SetAttributes[iteratedTable,HoldAll]

iteratedTable[e_, g:{__Symbol}, max_] := Block[g, 
    g = Thread[Indexed[\[FormalL], Range@Length@g]];
    Table[e, {\[FormalL], Subsets[Range@max, {Length@g}]}]
]
```

Examples:

```
iteratedTable[h[a,c], {a,b,c}, 5]
```

> {h[1, 3], h[1, 4], h[1, 5], h[1, 4], h[1, 5], h[1, 5], h[2, 4], h[2, 5], 
>    h[2, 5], h[3, 5]}

```
progress=0;
iteratedTable[progress++, {l1, l2, l3}, 40];
progress
```

> 9880

Comment: For those who want to keep the Letterspace'd variables: `ClearAll["g"];
X = 1;
Y = 50;
Table[With[{lhs = ToExpression["l\[LetterSpace]" <> ToString[i]]}, 
   lhs = Indexed[g, i]], {i, X}];
Table[{l\[LetterSpace]1}, {g, Subsets[Range[Y], {X}]}]`